# how to display bar values in horizontal stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am new to D3, developed a horizontal stacked bar chart, but facing issues to display bar values at the right corner of the bar.

```js
var group = ["field2", "field3"];
var mainDiv = "#charts";
var mainDivName = "charts";
var axisBottom;
var axisLeft;
var dealsData = [{
        field1: "company-1",
        field2: 500.0,
        field3: 400.0,
    },
    {
        field1: "company-2",
        field2: 200.0,
        field3: 700.0,
    },
    {
        field1: "company-3",
        field2: 113.2,
        field3: 850.0,
    },
    {
        field1: "company-4",
        field2: 140.4,
        field3: 83.0,
    },
    {
        field1: "company-5",
        field2: 75.5,
        field3: 27.5,
    },
    {
        field1: "company-6",
        field2: 140.0,
        field3: 440.0,
    },
    {
        field1: "company-6",
        field2: 79.5,
        field3: 107.5,
    },
];

var layers = d3.stack().keys(group).offset(d3.stackOffsetDiverging)(
    dealsData
);

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 50,
        left: 80,
    },
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var x = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([margin.left, width - margin.right]);

x.domain([d3.min(layers, stackMin), d3.max(layers, stackMax)]);

var y = d3
    .scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])
    .padding(0.5);

y.domain(
    dealsData.map(function(d) {
        return d.field1;
    })
);

function stackMin(layers) {
    return d3.min(layers, function(d) {
        return d[0];
    });
}

function stackMax(layers) {
    return d3.max(layers, function(d) {
        return d[1];
    });
}
this.axisBottom = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(-430);

var colors = ["#00FF00", "#FF0000"];
var eleX = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.bottom) + ")")
    .call(this.axisBottom);

eleX
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", width / 2)
    .attr("y", margin.bottom * 1)
    .attr("dx", "0.32em")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(" x- axis");
eleX
    .selectAll("line")
    .style("stroke-width", "0.6")
    .style("opacity", "0.25")
    .style("stroke", "#adadad");
eleX
    .selectAll("path")
    .style("stroke-width", "1")
    .style("opacity", "0")
    .style("stroke", "#adadad");

var bw = y.bandwidth;
console.log('bw', bw);
console.log("bandwidth::", bw);
var ele = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
ele
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("dx", "15px")
    .attr("dy", y.bandwidth)
    .style("font", "Source Sans Pro Regular")
    .style("fill", "#6C6F78");
ele
    .selectAll("rect")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("dx", "288px")
    .attr("dy", "-15px");
ele
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("x", 0 - height / 2)
    .attr("y", 60 - margin.left)
    .attr("dy", "0.32em")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(" y-axis");
ele.selectAll("line").style("stroke-width", "1").style("opacity", "1");
//.style('stroke-dasharray', '2,2');
ele.selectAll("path").attr("opacity", "0");

var maing = svg.append("g").selectAll("g").data(layers);
var g = maing
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return colors[i];
    });

var bars = g
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) {
        d.forEach(function(d1) {
            d1.key = d.key;
            return d1;
        });
        return d;
    })
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("data", function(d) {
        var data = {};
        data["key"] = d.key;
        data["value"] = d.data[d.key];
        data["name"] = d.data.field1;
        var total = 0;
        group.map(function(d1) {
            total = total + d.data[d1];
        });
        data["total"] = total;
        console.log("tooltip", data);
        return JSON.stringify(data);
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
        return x(d[1]) - x(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.data.field1);
    })
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth)
    .attr("rx", 2)
    .attr("ry", 2);
bars.append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.data.field2) + 3;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
        console.log("bars data : " + d.data.field2 + "/" + d.data.field3)
        return d.data.field2 + "/" + d.data.field3;
    });
```

```html
<div id="charts">
  <svg width="710" height="500"></svg>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.9.1/d3- 
tip.min.js"></script>
```

Let's say company 1 has data **500.0** and **400.0**, then we need to display **500/400** at end of the bar.
The bar values not appearing, how to display respective rendered bar values at the right corner of the bar.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: I have tried below code                                                                              `bars.append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", function (d) {
                return x(d.data.field2) + 3;
            })
      .text(function (d) {
               console.log("bars data : "+d.data.field2 + "/" +d.data.field3)
                return d.data.field2 + "/" +d.data.field3;
            })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to append a `text` to a `rect` element, they're not meant to have children. You can instead just draw another `g` node, and use the data from the final group of bars. The data contain everything you need - they know the `x` value of the highest bar, so they know the offset, and they also have the data in their `d.data` property:

```js
var group = ["field2", "field3"];
var mainDiv = "#charts";
var mainDivName = "charts";
var axisBottom;
var axisLeft;
var dealsData = [{
        field1: "company-1",
        field2: 500.0,
        field3: 400.0,
    },
    {
        field1: "company-2",
        field2: 200.0,
        field3: 700.0,
    },
    {
        field1: "company-3",
        field2: 113.2,
        field3: 850.0,
    },
    {
        field1: "company-4",
        field2: 140.4,
        field3: 83.0,
    },
    {
        field1: "company-5",
        field2: 75.5,
        field3: 27.5,
    },
    {
        field1: "company-6",
        field2: 140.0,
        field3: 440.0,
    },
    {
        field1: "company-6",
        field2: 79.5,
        field3: 107.5,
    },
];

var layers = d3.stack().keys(group).offset(d3.stackOffsetDiverging)(
    dealsData
);

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 50,
        left: 80,
    },
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var x = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([margin.left, width - margin.right]);

x.domain([d3.min(layers, stackMin), d3.max(layers, stackMax)]);

var y = d3
    .scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])
    .padding(0.5);

y.domain(
    dealsData.map(function(d) {
        return d.field1;
    })
);

function stackMin(layers) {
    return d3.min(layers, function(d) {
        return d[0];
    });
}

function stackMax(layers) {
    return d3.max(layers, function(d) {
        return d[1];
    });
}
this.axisBottom = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(-430);

var colors = ["#00FF00", "#FF0000"];
var eleX = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.bottom) + ")")
    .call(this.axisBottom);

eleX
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", width / 2)
    .attr("y", margin.bottom * 1)
    .attr("dx", "0.32em")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(" x- axis");
eleX
    .selectAll("line")
    .style("stroke-width", "0.6")
    .style("opacity", "0.25")
    .style("stroke", "#adadad");
eleX
    .selectAll("path")
    .style("stroke-width", "1")
    .style("opacity", "0")
    .style("stroke", "#adadad");

var bw = y.bandwidth;
console.log('bw', bw);
console.log("bandwidth::", bw);
var ele = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
ele
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("dx", "15px")
    .attr("dy", y.bandwidth)
    .style("font", "Source Sans Pro Regular")
    .style("fill", "#6C6F78");
ele
    .selectAll("rect")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("dx", "288px")
    .attr("dy", "-15px");
ele
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("x", 0 - height / 2)
    .attr("y", 60 - margin.left)
    .attr("dy", "0.32em")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(" y-axis");
ele.selectAll("line").style("stroke-width", "1").style("opacity", "1");
//.style('stroke-dasharray', '2,2');
ele.selectAll("path").attr("opacity", "0");

var maing = svg.append("g").selectAll("g").data(layers);
var g = maing
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return colors[i];
    });

var bars = g
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) {
        d.forEach(function(d1) {
            d1.key = d.key;
            return d1;
        });
        return d;
    })
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("data", function(d) {
        var data = {};
        data["key"] = d.key;
        data["value"] = d.data[d.key];
        data["name"] = d.data.field1;
        var total = 0;
        group.map(function(d1) {
            total = total + d.data[d1];
        });
        data["total"] = total;
        console.log("tooltip", data);
        return JSON.stringify(data);
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
        return x(d[1]) - x(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.data.field1);
    })
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth)
    .attr("rx", 2)
    .attr("ry", 2);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "labels")
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(layers[layers.length - 1]) // this has all the information we need
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d[1]) + 10;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.data.field1) + y.bandwidth() / 2;
  })
  .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.data.field1 + " / " + d.data.field2;
  });
```

```html
<div id="charts">
  <svg width="710" height="500"></svg>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.9.1/d3- 
tip.min.js"></script>
```

Note that there is some problem with a bar being drawn at the wrong place or being drawn twice it seems. That was a pre-existing problem with your graph, it's now only clearer because it means an extra label is drawn as well.